# How to send Ctrl + / to the stdin in Linux via byte string in Python?

Tags: python, stdin, ctrl, asyncssh

I know I can send `b'\x03'` to send `CTRL + C` to Linux but I don't know the code for `CTRL + \`. What resource covers `CTRL + <key>`?

By way of background, I am writing a small test script that exercises my python asyncssh application and I am using ping as a way to prove out the function of the code. One of the tests I wanted to include was sending a command while ping was running and have the script read the intermediary statistic output. When you run `ping localhost`, you can send `CTRL + \` in LINUX and this outputs 'N/N ... statistic summary: min/max... etc'. I send `CTRL + C` with `b'\x03'` just fine but can't figure out how to send `CTRL + \`. Any help?

Comment: 0x1c according https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending ASCII Control codes with asyncssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718149/sending-ascii-control-codes-with-asyncssh)