# Sending ASCII Control codes with asyncssh

Tags: python, ssh, stdin, asyncssh

I am writing a small test script that exercises asyncssh facilities. One of the test scenarios is running `ping localhost` process and then sending `CTRL+\` to report intermediary summary. However I have been unsuccessful sending ASCII control codes. Here is some test code:

```
async def test_control_code():
  async with asyncssh.connect(host='localhost', username='user', password='userpw', known_hosts=None) as conn: 
    async with conn.create_process('ping localhost') as proc: 
      proc._stdin.write(b'\x1c') # Error, says can't send in bytes

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  asyncio.run(test_control_code())
```

How can I send `CTRL + \` to the running process using asyncssh?

Comment: Doesn't `('\x1c')` work?

Comment: It doesn't appear to.

Comment: @Tim I'm assuming you are suggesting to send it as a tuple of strings.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting sending a normal (Unicode) string instead of a bytes string.

Comment: also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the problem.  The `ping` command does not look for the Ctrl-\ sequence.  Indeed, `ping` doesn't read from stdin at all, so nothing you send will affect it in any way.

When you type Ctrl-\ in a Linux terminal session, the terminal emulator generates a SIGQUIT signal to the foreground process.  That's what `ping` is looking for.  Since you don't have a terminal session, there's nobody to make that translation.

So, instead of forcing characters, just send the signal directly:

```
    proc.send_signal(signal.SIGQUIT)
```